# Oursql insallation failing wtih "cython not found"

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, oursql

Trying to install oursql driver for python3x and sqlalchemy0.8 on ubuntu 12.10. It fails with the following error.

```
sudo pip-3.2 install oursql
Downloading/unpacking oursql
Running setup.py egg_info for package oursql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build/oursql/setup.py", line 53
    print "cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file."
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build/oursql/setup.py", line 53

print "cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file."

                                                           ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I try to install **cython** I seem to already have it:

```
sudo pip-3.2 install cython
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
Cleaning up.
```

What can I do to make it run?

Comment: There is a bug about this on the OurSQL bug tracker, although it's not clear what the status is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/oursql/+bug/1040093

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same error when running pip-3.2.

This is how I made it work:

Created my *env* using *python-3.2*:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.2
```

Installed the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev

sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then installed:

```
sudo pip install cython

sudo pip install oursql
```

**Edit1:**

I was able to get pass you error with my above recomendations, but i was wrong (python3.2 was unable to read oursql). I tried the following and was able to make a connection:

First:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.2-dev
```

Then installed *oursql* for Python 3 from source (as suggested by it's maintainer [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/oursql/+bug/906007)):

> Get the Python 3 version of *oursql* from [here](https://launchpad.net/oursql/py3k) and compile it from source (Don't have enough reputation to post the link, just go to oursql official site for installation instructions).

Answer (score 1):

The maintainers have two packages, one for python 2.x and one for python 3.x, you should run:

`pip install oursql3`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about cython.

You just encoutered a syntax error in print, because the `print` statement doesn't use brackets there. They were optional in Python 2's `print` statement, but are required in  Python 3's `print()` function.

install it manually - reqs: `python-dev, cython`

then download oursql package (try 0.9.3.zip)
and
`python setup.py install`